# Shopify App / Invalid URI: Hostname cant be parsed

Tags: c#, shopify, shopify-app

I have been trying to figure this out for almost 48 hours and i cant seem to understand the issue, my Install works and loads correctly. However when it redirects to Auth, I get a crazy not found error ([open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9p0s.png))

after breaking code down I get a popup from visual studio saying "invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed" ([open image](https://ibb.co/npBj8o))

Here is my code:

```
// GET: fulfillment
    public ActionResult Install(string shop, string signature, string timestamp)
    {
        string r = string.Format("https://{0}/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={1}&scope=read_fulfillments,write_fulfillments&redirect_uri=https://{2}/fulfillment/Auth", shop, apiKey, appUrl);
        return Redirect(r);
    }



    public ActionResult Auth(string shop, string code)
    {
      string u = string.Format("https://{0}/admin/oauth/access_token", shop);

      var client = new RestClient(u);
      var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST){RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};

       request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "client_id=" + apiKey + "&client_secret=" + secretKey + "&code=" + code, ParameterType.RequestBody);

       var response = client.Execute(request);
       var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
       var access = r.access_token;

        return View();
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I am quite eager to learn :D

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag is for questions relating to the Visual Studio IDE.  It's also impossible for us to help you if you don't provide a sample value for `u` that's failing.

Comment: Oh im sorry I was not aware I will remove it, also I attached my code with the "string u = string.Format) value", is that what you mean?

Comment: No. Look at this: `string u = string.Format("https://{0}/admin/oauth/access_token", shop);` Your format code will replace `{0}` with the value held by the variable `shop`. It's likely that the combination of the two is an invalid URL, hence the error. The only way to find out is to inspect the value with the debugger.

Comment: I found this inside the debug right before the error came up, still am not able to find out what it means :/  `Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`

Comment: Look, the error message simply states that the URL created by the `string.Format(....)` is invalid, in the same way that `https:////admin/oauth/access_token` would be invalid. You need to find out why. The only way it can be invalid, from the code you have, is if the value of `shop` makes it invalid. Set a [breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) on `var client = `, run your code. When the breakpoint is hit, hover over `u` and look at the url it contains.

Comment: Check the content of the `string shop` variable. That is probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Also take a look at this [debugging tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging).

Comment: Im learning alot, thank you. I have done what you said and saw the shop variable, which is [click for image](https://ibb.co/fe0Boo). it looks like im missing a "/" ? Nvm. I dont think that would make sense either, to me it looks like it should work?

Comment: Can you press F11 (step into) and show the value of `u` after the `string.Format`?

Comment: I did as you said here is an image. Looks correct again. [click for image](https://ibb.co/k1ZMoo)

Comment: This is the main error that Im concerned with.. which means its in this auth code, but I see anythingwrong with it. If I return the value as null instead of view, it can find it and brings up a blank page. [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9p0s.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with RestSharp, but perhaps you need to pass `https://ochrom-base-reborn.myshopify.com` to `RestClient` and then `admin/oauth/access_token` to `RestRequest` (as per the [example here](http://restsharp.org/)). RestSharp may be building an invalid URL if you do it your way. Again, I'm not familiar with RS. If it works, let me know and I'll add an answer.

Comment: To my knowledge I cant see anything wrong :/ I did some deep looking on the console and found this.. Cant figure out why though? [click for image](https://ibb.co/dR3vg8)